# Corona SDK composer.removeScene()

Tags: lua, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

Is

```
composer.removeScene( "gameScene")
composer.loadScene( "gameScene")
composer.gotoScene("gameScene")
```

equal to

```
composer.gotoScene("gameScene")
```

assuming first calling?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but in my opinion they are equal. I recommended you read  about it in Corona [documention](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/system/composer/index.html#flow).